# pxe boot fails with message: no DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found

Tags: ubuntu, pxe-boot, ubuntu-10.10, tftp

I am trying to pxe-boot a machine (client), and in the process I am trying to setup a tftp server that this machine can boot off.

On the server, which runs Ubuntu 10.10, I have setup dhcp, dns, nfs, and tftp-hpa servers.  All the servers/deamons start fine.  I tested the tftp server by using a tftp client and downloading a file that the server directory hosts.

My /etc/xinet.d/tftp looks like this

```
service tftp
{
    disable                 = no
    socket_type             = dgram
    wait                    = yes
    user                    = nobody
    server                  = /usr/sbin/in.tftpd
    server_args             = -v -s /var/lib/tftpboot
    only_from   = 10.1.0.0/24
    interface   = 10.1.0.1
}
```

My /etc/default/tftpd-hpa looks like this

```
RUN_DAEMON="yes"
OPTIONS="-l -s /var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

My `/var/lib/tftpboot/` directory looks like this

```
 initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic-pae
 vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic-pae
 pxelinux.0
 pxelinux.cfg
   -- default
```

I did

```
 sudo chmod 644 /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default
 chmod 755 /var/lib/tftpboot/initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic-pae
 chmod 755 /var/lib/tftpboot/vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic-pae
```

/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg has the following contents

```
 SERIAL 0 19200 0
 LABEL linux
 KERNEL vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic-pae
 APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-2.6.35-25-generic-pae nfsroot=10.1.0.1:/nfsroot ip=dhcp console=ttyS0,19200n8 rw
```

I copied `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0` from `/usr/lib/syslinux/` after installing the package `syslinux-common`.

Also just for completeness, `/etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf` the following lines (relevant to this interface)

```
subnet 10.1.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 10.1.0.100 10.1.0.240;
  option routers 10.1.0.1;
  option broadcast-address 10.1.0.255;
  option domain-name-servers 10.1.0.1;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
}
```

When I boot the client machine, and watch the output over the serial port, I notice that the client requests an ip address from the server and gets it.  Then I see TFTP being displayed - indicating that it is trying to connect to the TFTP server.  This succeeds, and I see `TFTP.|`, which return immediately displaying the following message

```
PXELINUX 4.01 debian-20100714  Copyright (C) 1994-2010 H. Peter Anvin et al
No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found!
boot:
```

`/var/log/syslog` shows

```
Feb 20 15:24:05 ch in.tftpd[2821]: tftp: client does not accept options
```

What option is it talking about in the syslog? I assume it is referring to OPTIONS or TFTP_OPTIONS, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turns out some more googling pointed to the fact that "tftp: client does not accept options" is a benign message (http://syslinux.zytor.com/archives/2003-June/002093.html). So I just replaced my pxelinux.0 (which i got from the syslinux package) with a version of this file i had backed-up.  pxe boot goes through now and i don't get the error message "no DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found" any more.  I don't want to post an answer to my own question and select it as the best answer, so I guess the new question I have is - what is the correct way to get the *right pxelinux.0* file? :)

Comment: There is no *right* pxelinoux.0. The only thing to keep in mind is that you should not mix syslinux binaries from different versions (e.g. pxelinux.0 from an old package with menu.c32 from a newer one)

Answer (score 5):

for "**no default or ui configuration directive found**"
try change

```
from  KERNEL vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic-pae
      APPEND ....optopns...
to    DEFAULT vmlinuz-2.6.35-25-generic-pae ....options...
```

or use UI menu.
it help me with ubuntu 10.10 pxeboot.0

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the default in DEFAULT file - in your case the
`/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg` should have

```
"DEFAULT linux"
```

line at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to use correct versions of menu.c32 or vesamenu.c32. Otherwise you'll get the error message: "Menu.c32 not a com32r file". The correct versions of those files can be found from /boot directory. Also, if the parent system is 64 bit you'll need the 32 bit libraries installed.
At the above example "default menu.c32" doesn't work anymore, it should stay: UI menu.c32 or UI vesamenu.c32.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the default entry in `/var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default`

I had the same problem.

Here is the contents of my default file:

```
DEFAULT menu.c32

prompt 0

timeout 5

LABEL linux

        menu default
        menu label Linux
        KERNEL fc1/vmlinuz-2.4.22-1.2115.nptl
        APPEND initrd=fc1/pxeboot.img.gz ramdisk=8192
```

**menu default** is necessary.

Here is the entry in the [Syslinux wiki](http://syslinux.zytor.com/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX#DEFAULT_command)